# Is there a way to determine device orientation if view is loaded before [window makeKeyAndVisible] is called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

View of my `UIViewController` is loaded from a NIB before `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` is called in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` so I cannot get the correct device orientation - i.e. `self.interfaceOrientation`, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` and `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` all give me false orientation info that I'm in portrait mode (iPad's default mode, I think).

Is there any way to work around that problem? Please don't say I need to use accelerometer ;)

**EDIT:** for whose who are interested on getting orientation info based on accelerometer reading: [http://web.archive.org/web/20091111033649/http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-accelerometer-device-orientation](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-accelerometer-device-orientation/)

Answer (score 1):

it appears that you can't rely on `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` until the orientation actually changes for the first time.  If so, you could probably hack it by getting raw accelerometer readings.

```
#define kUpdateFrequency 30  // Hz
#define kUpdateCount 15 // So we init after half a second
#define kFilteringFactor (1.0f / kUpdateCount)

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app
{
    [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].updateInterval = (1.0 / kUpdateFrequency);
    [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = self;
    accelerometerCounter = 0;
    ...
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)accel
{
    // Average out the first kUpdateCount readings
    // acceleration_[xyz] are ivars typed float
    acceleration_x = (float)accel.x * kFilteringFactor + acceleration_x * (1.0f - kFilteringFactor);
    acceleration_y = (float)accel.y * kFilteringFactor + acceleration_y * (1.0f - kFilteringFactor);
    acceleration_z = (float)accel.z * kFilteringFactor + acceleration_z * (1.0f - kFilteringFactor);

    accelerometerCounter++;
    if (accelerometerCounter == kUpdateCount)
    {
        [self initOrientation];
        [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = nil;
    }
}

- (void)initOrientation
{
    // Figure out orientation from acceleration_[xyz] and set up your UI...
}
```

---

**Original response:**

Does `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` return the correct orientation during `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`?  If so, you can set up your initial UI according to that orientation.

If that property doesn't get set until some later time, you might try experimenting with `performSelector:afterDelay:` to initialize the UI after a small delay.

This code sample is from Kendall's answer below, added here for completeness:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(getOriented) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

I'm not sure if a zero-second delay is sufficient -- this means the code for `getOriented` will run during the first pass through the event run loop.  You may need to wait longer for the accelerometer readings to register on `UIDevice`.

Comment: accelerometer is a last resort. Do you have any idea why my view is loaded before [window makeKeyAndVisible] is called?

Comment: find a way to get orientation via accelerometer (see EDIT in question), but this doesn't help since status bar is already rotated to portrait...

Answer (score 1):

I found that the only workable solution was to implement layoutSubviews for the main view and do the reorientation of the layout there (via a call back into my view controller).

Once you're at that point UIViewController.interfaceOrientation appears to be reliable.

Comment: seems a way to go, so I'll check it later, however got a feeling that with my status bar already rotated I won't be able to achieve much. Anyway, thank you for sharing your idea :)